# Add 2 fields then subtract a fixed value

Tags: sql

I wanted to add the 2 fields to get the total amount and after which I will subtract it from a fixed value. Below is my code.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[School_Year_Amount]
AS SELECT 
ISNULL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), -1) AS sID,
Parent_Share_Amount.trans_name AS parent_trans_name,
OJT_Share_Amount.trans_name AS ojt_trans_name,
Parent_Share_Amount.ID_Number AS ID_Number, 
Parent_Share_Amount.adviser_info_id AS adviser_info_id, 
Parent_Share_Amount.student_fname AS student_fname, Parent_Share_Amount.student_lname AS student_lname,
Parent_Share_Amount.student_info_id AS student_info_id,
Parent_Share_Amount.amount AS parent_amount,
OJT_Share_Amount.amount AS ojt_amount,
SUM(OJT_Share_Amount.amount + Parent_Share_Amount.amount) AS total_amount,
(120000 - SUM(OJT_Share_Amount.amount + Parent_Share_Amount.amount)) AS total_balance
FROM [Parent_Share_Amount]
LEFT OUTER JOIN OJT_Share_Amount ON Parent_Share_Amount.student_info_id = OJT_Share_Amount.student_info_id;
```

PLease help me with this one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[School_Year_Amount]
AS SELECT 
ISNULL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), -1) AS sID,
Parent_Share_Amount.trans_name AS parent_trans_name,
OJT_Share_Amount.trans_name AS ojt_trans_name,
Parent_Share_Amount.ID_Number AS ID_Number, 
Parent_Share_Amount.adviser_info_id AS adviser_info_id, 
Parent_Share_Amount.student_fname AS student_fname,     
Parent_Share_Amount.student_lname AS student_lname,
Parent_Share_Amount.student_info_id AS student_info_id,
Parent_Share_Amount.amount AS parent_amount,
OJT_Share_Amount.amount AS ojt_amount,
isnull(OJT_Share_Amount.amount,0) + isnull(Parent_Share_Amount.amount,0) AS total_amount,
(120000 - isnull(OJT_Share_Amount.amount,0) - isnull(Parent_Share_Amount.amount,0)) AS total_balance
FROM [Parent_Share_Amount]
LEFT OUTER JOIN OJT_Share_Amount
ON Parent_Share_Amount.student_info_id = OJT_Share_Amount.student_info_id;
```

You don't need to use `sum` to add your values.

Comment: Thanks and it is working. But when the one of the amount field is null the total amount is null as well. How can I set the value into zero it the amount is null?

Comment: use `isnull` function

Comment: could you give me one sample on how to implement it?

Comment: modified the query to include `isnull`. You may have to change it based on the database you use.